# as.numeric(as.factor(x)) : why this expression can rerank noncontinuous data sequence

Tags: r

I have a group variable with a non-contunoious number label

```
  user_id<-c(2,5,7,9)
```

I want to rename the `user_id` with a continuous number. The following code will work. But I want to know why? And is there any other way

```
new_id<- as.numeric(as.factor(user_id))
new_id
output:
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use `seq_along(user_id)` to create the new id

```
user_id <- c(2,5,7,9)
new_id  <- seq_along(user_id)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

**EDIT**

As a follow up to the comment by @MatthewLundberg, here is a version which will take in to consideration duplicate user IDs; this uses the `dplyr` function `dense_rank`.  This assumes a duplicate would get the same "new_id".

```
library(dplyr)

user_id <- c(2, 5, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7)
new_id  <- dense_rank(user_id)
new_id
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1 1 3
```

Comment: This assumes no repeated values in `user_id`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg The original post doesn't really state the expected result when there are duplicates, however, I posted an additional possible solution.

Comment: Hi Steveb, even if there are duplicates in user_id, as.numeric(as.factor(x)) also works, right?

Comment: @Phdaml Yes, your factor solution works.  Perhaps more info was given as an answer than was asked for.  akrun directly answers your question of why  factor works.  Given my answer just adds info and doesn't really address the initial question, I can remove it if it is out of place.  It is just an alternate way to approach sequentially numbering.

Answer (score 3):

The internal representation of `factor` levels are `integer`  So, when we coerce to numeric directly, it will convert to that integer values.  It is just a coincidence that the OP got the intended output here.  Suppose, we create a new vector by `sample`ing.

```
 set.seed(24)
 v1 <- sample(letters[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE)
 as.numeric(factor(v1))
 #[1] 2 1 3 3 3 4 2 4 4 2
```

where

```
 v1
 #[1] "b" "a" "c" "c" "c" "d" "b" "d" "d" "b"
```

Note that the values is repeated and it is not the expected output of sequence.

If we need to create the same as 'new_id'

```
 seq(length(user_id))
```